# Core Data - How to Insert an Array

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios4, core-data

I'd like to know how to save several string objects, all stored in an array, using Core Data.

I understand how to store a single string, but is there any convenience method/can I store the array object itself rather than iterating over the array and storing each string item seperately?

```
NSManagedObject *alice = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Student" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[alice setValue:@"Alice" forKey:@"name"];
[alice setValue:@"Computer Science" forKey:@"major"];
```

Basically, can I have setValue be an array instead of Alice?

(As an unrelated question how can I cache data on the iphone, such as an image...)

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Look at this post : [insert NSDictionary into CoreData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682324/insert-nsdictionary-into-coredata/8682430#8682430) just replace the word `NSDictionary` by `NSArray` apart from that it's the same question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there are any prebuilt methods. You'd have to track keys in a separate container, for example, or define them as constants somewhere, such as in the following example:

```
static NSUInteger const kMyNameIdx = 0U;
static NSUInteger const kMyMajorIdx = 1U;
static NSString * const kMyNameKey = @"name";
static NSString * const kMyMajorKey = @"major";

/* this does no error checking on the mo or array */
/* being null. it would be better to return an    */
/* NSError from this function and check its value */
/* to handle error cases                          */

- (void) updateManagedObject:(NSManagedObject *)mo withOrderedArray:(NSArray *)array
{
    id obj;
    NSUInteger objIdx = 0U;

    /* this assumes that name and major objects in */
    /* your array are in the same order as set by  */
    /* the constants                               */

    for (obj in array) {
        switch (objIdx) { 
            case kMyNameIdx:
                [mo setValue:obj forKey:kMyNameKey];
                break;
            case kMyMajorIdx:
                [mo setValue:obj forKey:kMyMajorKey];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        objIdx++;
    }
}
```

To use it:

```
NSManagedObject *alice = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Student" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSArray *myArray = /* ... */
[self updateManagedObject:alice withOrderedArray:myArray];
```

There are additional modifications you can make, such as making this a [category method](http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-categories.html) for `NSManagedObject` of entity type `Student`. Then you can call this function anywhere you use `Student` managed objects.

Answer (score 0):

where ever you called this method with your array

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
  [self insertLoginData:YOUR ARRAY NAME];
}

- (BOOL)insertLoginData:(NSMutableArray *)loginInfoArray
{
    NSError *error=nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSManagedObject *propertyInfo = [NSEntityDescription
                                     insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"UserLogin" 
                                     inManagedObjectContext:context];
    for(int count=0;count<[loginInfoArray count];count++)
    {
        [propertyInfo setValue:[[loginInfoArray objectAtIndex:count]objectForKey:@"UserId"] forKey:@"userName"];
        [propertyInfo setValue:[[loginInfoArray objectAtIndex:count]objectForKey:@"Password"] forKey:@"password"];  
    }

    if (![__managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        return NO;
    }
    else  
    {
        return YES; 
    }
}
```

Fetch data ==========

```
-(NSMutableArray *)fetchLoginData
{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchReq = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];

    [fetchReq setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"UserLogin" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]];
    NSMutableArray *resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchReq error:nil]];
    NSMutableArray *array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for(UserLogin *pnt in resultArray)
    {
        //[array addObject:pnt.userName];
        [array addObject:pnt];
    }
    return array;
}
```