# What's the right solution for storing a large amount of key-value pairs? NSDictionary vs DB

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite, nsdictionary

I need to replace words with other words from a dictionary. The dictionary contains around ~1500 key-value-pairs (all NSStrings containing a word which should get replaced by another word). The dictionary is build up dynamically. Using a database looks like an over heap to me, but storing all the words in a dictionary doesn't feel good too. (They may be stored for a longer time and in rare cases also get stored too disk too.)

What would be the right solution in this case on an iOS application?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682324/insert-nsdictionary-into-coredata

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1500 key-value pairs that are word -> word?

That isn't large.  That is pretty tiny, actually.

Just stick 'em in an NSDictionary and write it to storage as a plist.

Make sure access to said dictionary is isolated behind a class's interface such that any future need for expansion that might cause a size explosion can be done entirely behind said interface without impacting clients.