# Core Data Binary Data type loading doesn't release memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, memory-management

I have a `Core Data` attribute that is a `Binary Data` type. We use `NSArchiver` to archive an `NSArray` of custom objects and then save that in `Core Data`.

Then when needing those objects we use `NSUnarchiver` to turn that back into an `NSArray`.

The problem with this is it uses up a lot of memory and I can never get that back for some reason. After unarchiving the data, checking some of the objects and then setting the `NSArray` or `NSData` object to nil, that memory is never recovered. Doing this same action to many `Core Data` entities results in huge memory usage that is never returned.

Is there a reason why this would happen, or a way I can release that memory that I am clearly not using anymore?

**Edit:**

I have done the following without success:

```
[managedObjectContext refreshObject:myObject mergeChanges:NO];
```

Comment: Just adding another information. Instead of archiving the NSArray into data use TRANSFORMABLE data type available in coredata.  For eexample http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682324/insert-nsdictionary-into-coredata/25891673#25891673

Comment: Did you try doing that task inside an `@autoreleasepool` block?

Comment: @KrishnaCA Yes, but this didn't seem to help.

Comment: @Gagan_iOS I don't want to change the data type. I am updating the database and moving away from Binary Data all together, but don't need a new type.

Answer (score 0):

I got a same problem. It generates a lot of temporary memory when I use NSUnarchiver to unarchive the data, and the temporary memory not be released. I solved it by adding @autoreleasepool，like @KrishnaCA said. Is it not appropriate for the code you added? If you show your simple code, this helps solve the problem.

Comment: Where are you adding it? Around the code where you use `NSUnarchiver`?

Comment: From the start use of NSUnarchiver, to the final use of the data obtained by NSUnarchiver.